# create a list in a specific order from another list-python

Tags: python

I have a list of 2 items, from which I would like to create a second list and put it in a specified order.

```
list1 = ['team01', 'team02']
```

we only know that we have elements that end with 01 and elements that end with 02 (but we don't know that the prefix is "team")

I want to create this list:

```
list2 = ['team01v', 'team01', 'team02', 'team01sp', 'team02sp']
```

Note :
add the 'v' only for the element that ends with 01, and add the "sp" for all the elements. The order must therefore be:

_____01v
_____01
_____02
_____01sp
_____02sp

how can we do that? helppp please

Comment: what is your code so far?

Comment: You need custom script, it's not related to python features.

Comment: You've said add `'v'` for the elements ending with `'01'`, so then why is the second `'team01'` with a `'sp'` suffix?

Comment: I said "and add the "sp" for all the elements" , that mean that we add SP for elements that end with 01 and 02 :)

Comment: Build your new list in 3 steps. Also the string function `endswith` helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
list1 = ['team01', 'team02']
final_list = [i+'v' for i in list1 if i.endswith('01')] + list1 + [i+'sp' for i in list1]
```

So, when you print `final_list`, the value will be as shown below

```
 ['team01v', 'team01', 'team02', 'team01sp', 'team02sp']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but it works:

```
list1 = ['team01', 'team02']
tag = list1[0][:-2] # Get the tag 'team' before the number
list2 = [element for element in list1]
for element in list1:
    list2.append(element+'sp')

list2.insert(0, tag+'01v')

print(list2)
```

It will print `['team01v', 'team01', 'team02', 'team01sp', 'team02sp']`.

Edit:
Note that it will work only if the elements are already sorted and if the ID after the name (01 after team) is composed by 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['team01', 'team02']

v_list = [item + 'v' for item in list1 if item.endswith('01')]
sp_list = [item + 'sp' for item in list1]

list2 = v_list + list1 + sp_list
```

Answer (score 0):

below

```
list1 = ['team01', 'team02']
list2 = []
for e in list1:
    if e.endswith('01'):
        list2.append(e + 'v')
    list2.append(e + 'sp')
    list2.append(e)

print(list2)
```

output

```
['team01v', 'team01sp', 'team01', 'team02sp', 'team02']
```